# Modifying font size for pie chart lables

Tags: plot, octave, matlab-figure, pie-chart, label

I am using a simple script for a pie chart, but I am unable to change the font size of the pie labels. Is there an easy way to change it?

Below is my plotting code:

```
h = pie ([0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1], {"unlikely","possible","likely","very likely","certain"});
y = 0; 
n = 1; 

colormap([1 1 n;    %// unlikely
          1 1 y;    %// possible
          1 1 y;    %// likely
          1 1 y;    %// very unlikely
          1 1 n;])  %// certainly
ax = gca();
set(ax,'fontsize', 18);
view([270, -90])
```

Comment: In MATLAB, `h` contains an array of five `Patch` objects intertwined with 5 `Text` objects. If the Octave output follows the same convention, my best bet would be to do `set(h(2:2:end),'FontSize',16)`.

Comment: Thank you - that worked!

Comment: (I've posted that as an answer.)

Answer (score 0):

The variable `h` contains an array of five `Patch` objects intertwined with 5 `Text` objects. Use the following command to set all font sizes for the text objects.

```
set(h(2:2:end),'FontSize',16);
```

Answer (score 0):

To programmatically set the `fontsize` or any other property of graphical elements of a certain type you should use the **`findobj()`** function to find all elements of this type. Then you can use a single set command to set properties. In your example you have to write:

```
set(findobj(h,'type','text'),'fontsize',18)
```

This will change all font sizes of all text elements in the pie chart.

#### Complete Example

I adapted your example to show the effect:

```
h = pie ([0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1], {"unlikely","possible","likely","very likely","certain"});
y = 0; 
n = 1; 

colormap([1 1 n;    %// unlikely
          1 1 y;    %// possible
          1 1 y;    %// likely
          1 1 y;    %// very unlikely
          1 1 n;])  %// certainly

view([270, -90])
set(findobj(h,'type','text'),'fontsize',18);
```

#### Graphical Output

[image: Graphical output of pie chart after font resizing]