# Programmatically getting the labels in Octave

Tags: plot, octave, axis-labels

In Octave, when I plot I can get the plot object. For example

```
pl = get(plot(...))
```

I can then specify the labels such as:

```
xlabel("something")
```

I'm working on an auto-grader and need to check the contents of the xlabel from the plot object pl. I'd think I'd be able to say something like

```
disp(all(pl.xlabel == "something"))
```

But, I'm getting an error saying xlabel doesn't belong to the plot object.

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: Matlab switched from function syntax (e.g. `get(graphics_object, field)` to "struct syntax" (e.g. `graphics_object.field` ) some time in the last couple of years and currently supports both syntaxes. Octave may support "struct syntax" in the future, but for now only supports the "function syntax". Hence `pl.xlabel` does not apply in octave. Use the `get` / `set` functions on the appropriate objects that have the fields you're interested in instead (which is what you inadvertently show in your answer).

Comment: You could try an approach using `findobj()` I showed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47262876/modifying-font-size-for-pie-chart-lables/47315852#47315852. I guess you can modify it to find label strings too.

Comment: @excaza The error was that  xlabel is not a member of the plot handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is only one axis object, you could get the current axis object with gca, then get the labels and such through the axis object.

```
ax = gca
disp(get(get(ax, "XLabel") "String"))
```

If you have multiple plots on different figures and no handle to the figure, you could do the following where you get the figure, rather than directly use gca:

```
p1 = plot((1:10).^2);
p2 = plot((1:10).^4);
xlabel('Matt');
fig = ancestor(p1, 'figure');
ax = get(fig, "CurrentAxes");
disp(get(get(ax, "XLabel") "String"))
```